# How to fix or replace the arrow key of a laptop keyboard?

Tags: repair

I have a laptop which right arrow key often gets unclipped. I believe the key is indeed broken (see right circle in the picture). I would like to fix it or replace it (with a similar "key"). The laptop is a Dell Latitude E6410.

1. Would you agree the problem is the key and not the keyboard itself?
2. Where could I find a new key?

[image: Arrow key]

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/290464/57189

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please turn the key upside down see if any plastic is broken. If plastic is broken then you have to replace the key. If plastic is not broken, see on which side the key is tilted. Add a fixture to the side where the button is tilted.